# How to copy a python script which includes dictionaries to a new python script?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python script which contains dictionaries and is used as input from another python script which performs calculations. I want to use the first script which is used as input, to create more scripts with the exact same structure in the dictionaries but different values for the keys.

Original Script: Car1.py

```
Owner = {
"Name": "Jim",
"Surname": "Johnson",
}

Car_Type = {
"Make": "Ford",
"Model": "Focus",
"Year": "2008"
}

Car_Info = {
"Fuel": "Gas",
"Consumption": 5,
"Max Speed": 190
}
```

I want to be able to create more input files with identical format but for different cases, e.g.

New Script: Car2.py

```
Owner = {
"Name": "Nick",
"Surname": "Perry",
}

Car_Type = {
"Make": "BMW",
"Model": "528",
"Year": "2015"
}

Car_Info = {
"Fuel": "Gas",
"Consumption": 10,
"Max Speed": 280
}
```

So far, i have only seen answers that print just the keys and the values in a new file but not the actual name of the dictionary as well. Can someone provide some help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but you might be mistaking python files with data files. Python files are not meant as a way to store data and, even though it's technically possible, it's not a good idea and you won't find much support for doing that. Use an appropriate data format for that… YAML, JSON, … options are many.

Comment: How about a dictionary of dictionaries, `d = {'Owner': {}}`. So when you want to print the names of the dictionaries you can do `print(d.keys())` or `print d.keys()` in Python 2.

Comment: These are Python files that contain _Python code_. Do you want to _execute_ this data or just to store, access and modify it? If the latter, you need another storage facility, like SQL or mere JSON or something similar. Now, if you want to modify the data, the only way to do this is using your good old friend _the keyboard_ and Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V. Or pull that data automatically from some resource if you're using any.

Answer (score 0):

read the file with something like

```
text=open('yourfile.py','r').read().split('\n')
```

and then interpret the list of strings you get... after that you can save it with something like

```
new_text = open('newfile.py','w')
[new_text.write(line) for line in text]
new_text.close()
```

as spectras said earlier, not ideal... but if that's what you want to do... go for it

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it that way (not recommended, because of the reasons statet in the comment by spectras and good alternatives) and import your input Python file:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759820/how-to-get-a-list-of-variables-in-specific-python-module) question has answers on how to read out the dictionaries names from the imported module. (using the dict() on the module while filtering for variables that do not start with "__")
Then get the new values for the dictionary entries and construct the new dicts.
Finally you need to write a exporter that takes care of storing the data in a python readable form, just like you would construct a normal text file.

I do not see any advantage over just storing it in a storage format.