# How can I implicitly pass the current global namespace in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I would like to implicitly pass a reference of the current global namespace to a function so that I can edit it. I feel like it could be possible because `exec()` does it, but that may be too special of a case.

spam.py

```py
# This will fail because globals() grabs the spam.py globals
# I would like to to grab the globals from wherever it was called from

def writeOtherGlobals( implicitGlobals=globals() ):
    print "Got sausages", implicitGlobals['sausages']
    implicitGlobals['sausages'] = 10
```

eggs.py

```py
from spam import writeOtherGlobals
sausages = 5
writeOtherGlobals()
print sausages # I want this to print 10
```

Comment: I know this is generally a *terrible* idea, but my use case is pretty particular, and built on legacy code.

I'm working with a renderfarm that has to run multiple 3d apps (Maya, 3dsMax, Xsi, etc...) which do *basically* the same thing, so we built an abstraction layer. Our system checks the current app, and modifies the class's `__dict__` to swap in the app specific decorated methods. However, we have to do the app-specific imports at the top of every single method, and I'd like to fix that.

Comment: I'd put that in your original post instead of a comment, though I don't see why that means you need the global regardless. Couldn't you just import the other file and access the variables directly from a separate module?

Comment: I figured that having a clean question would be better. Either way: I can't just `import eggs` next to `writeOtherGlobals` because I don't know where it's being called from. I need to be able to reuse it multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import inspect

def get_globals():
    return inspect.stack(1)[1][0].f_globals
```

This function will return a dictionary of the globals for the context from which it was called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ['dir(module)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9759842/2036035) method, and exclude __ variables (to ignore **name** etc) or you might want to add a variable at the end of your module like so:

```
#in module.py
a = ...
b = ...
# function/class definitions etc...
_globals = globals()
```

so now you can do

```
# in anothermodule.py
import module
print module._globals
```

All your globals are now printed, and you can access each one as if you called globals() in the original class.

Note you don't need to know the name of `module.py` for this to work, as long as your module has a `._globals` it doesn't matter what it is named, ie this works

```
def get_globals(module_py):
    print(module_py._globals)
```

Comment: Can't do it for my use-case. `anothermodule.py` needs to be reusable, so it can't explicitly reference `module.py`

Comment: @TylerFox You don't need to, you can just set an arbitrary variable to your module, as long as they all have _globals it doesn't matter what they are called.

Comment: In your example, you would have to call `get_globals(my_module)` from somewhere that has a reference to my_module. Or `get_globals(sys.modules[__name__])` from within my_module. But the thing I'm trying to avoid is adding *any* boilerplate code to the get_globals call

Comment: I realize I'm being *really* difficult with this. The problem is, I'm trying to make a "magic" module. You've given me a good practical solution, I'm just looking for the magic one :)