# Find all local variables in a separate file

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I am trying to find a way to get all the variables from a python 3 file. The function `locals()` does not work, because I am trying to get all the variables from a different file, not the current file. I do not want to import all variables into that file, because the other python file I am getting variables from might have variables that might mess around with my code (`from file1 import *`).

For example:

file1.py

```
foo = 10
bar = "text"
```

file2.py

```
x = # function that I am looking for
print(x)

# should return something like {... "foo": 10, "bar": "text" ...}
```

I could use the `locals()` function in file1 to find the variables then write it to a file, then read it with file2, but that would be slow and not very elegant. Is the a better way to do this?

**EDIT**:
This is not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759820/how-to-get-a-list-of-variables-in-specific-python-module) because I do not want to use import statements at all. Is that possible?

Comment: `vars(file1)` would give you the global namespace of another module. Note that `locals()` is really the same thing as `globals()` when not inside a function.

Comment: `import file1`, `dir(file1)`

Comment: @MonLiH Are you just wanting variable names or the objects they refer to as well? You didn't say you didn't want to use `import` at all. Why is that? You're making your job much more difficult. Actually, why do you want to do this at all? You could use [**`ast.parse`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) to get an Abstract Syntax Tree and find all the name assignments.