# How to dynamically import ALL variables from ALL modules in a directory and put them in a list?

Tags: python

I want to import all variables from all modules inside a directory (and preferably put them in a list).

I have the following structure

```
Foo/
  bar1.py
  bar2.py
  bar3.py
```

Modules contain

```
# bar1.py
baz1 = "spam"
```

```
# bar2.py
baz2 = "chicken"
```

```
# bar3.py
baz3 = "milk"
```

How do I form a list with all the variables `baz1`, `baz2`, `baz3` without explicitly importing them and explicitly adding them to a list? In other words, after adding another `barx.py` module with another variable I want that variable to be implicitly loaded into the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import importlib

my_path = 'Foo'
lst = [f.rstrip('.py') for f in os.listdir(my_path) if f.endswith('.py')]

all_imported_data = dict()
for item in lst:
  module = importlib.import_module(f'{my_path}.{item}')
  all_imported_data.update({k: v for k, v in module.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('_')})

print(all_imported_data)
```

Documentation for importlib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: For including variables in the list, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759820/how-to-get-a-list-of-variables-in-specific-python-module

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar1'`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I updated the code, and it works on my machine.

Comment: You are very welcome :) I also learned a bit while debugging.