# How to reference a module by a variable name?

Tags: python

*I know the phrasing of this question may be a bit off, but please allow me explain. It's also a general python question, but I'm using a specific case to explain it*

---

[I'm working with a group of stylesheets or [themes](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/themes/) from [dash_bootstrap_components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/). And now I've stumbled upon a more general python problem that I've been wondering about for a while. You can set up a Dash app with the following snippet where the last line specifies a stylesheet:

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])
```

But let's say that I'd like to assign that theme using a variable name and not its explicit name `SLATE` - for example when setting another stylesheet or letting the particular stylesheet be an option for the users to select. How can I loop through the module or select a theme using a variable name instead of `SLATE`?

The post [How to get a list of variables in specific Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759820/how-to-get-a-list-of-variables-in-specific-python-module) shows how to loop through a module like this using:

```
[item for item in dir(dbc.themes) if not item.startswith("__")]
```

But I'd still need to select the theme somehow. These are some of the things I've tried:

```
myVar = 'SLATE'
themed_app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes[myVar])
```

I do realize that it's a lack of basic python understanding that's the problem here, but I would really like to know why this fails and what could be done instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getattr` to access an attribute dynamically.

```
themed_app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[getattr(dbc.themes, myVar)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` as another solution to access dynamically

```
var = "SLATE"
sheet = f"dbc.themes.{var}"    
themed_app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[eval(sheet)])
```