# As the class is also an object of type, is a class object created when the above code is executed?

Tags: python, class, object

```
class Test:
    def print_some():
        print('Good')
```

As the class is also an object of `type`, is a class object created when the above code is executed? If it does, how to prove the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759820/how-to-get-a-list-of-variables-in-specific-python-module

Comment: Please clarify what you consider adequate to "prove" an object is created. Everything referenced by a name is an object in Python, and classes clearly have a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `class` is an executable statement that defines an object.

```py
>>> class Cls:
...     print("This is executed as part of the `class` statement")
...
This is executed as part of `class` statement
>>> isinstance(Cls, object)
True
```

> #### The Python Language Reference: [Class definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions)
>
> A class definition defines a class object [...]
> A class definition is an executable statement.

---

Note that technically, the `class` statement is not required to *create* an object – the [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) can return an existing object. The builtin metaclasses, most prominently `type`, create new objects for each `class`.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's correct.

Actually `class` keyword causes that an instance of the type `type` created.
Same thing happens for `def` keyword. It causes that an instance of the type `Function` created.

```
import types

class A:
    pass


def fn():
    pass

print(isinstance(fn, types.FunctionType))
print(isinstance(A, type))
```

"A" is now an instance of the type "type".
"fn" is an instance of the type "Function".

Comment: So what's present in the instance of the ```type``` class?

Comment: @Cognoscenti I've add something to my answer. Because type "type" and "Functiontype" are not in globals(). To check the isinstances you have to first import types module. It is now same as isinstance(10, int)

Answer (score 0):

When a class definition (of `ClassA`, for example) is first executed:

- A `type` object is created to hold the class definition.
- A name `ClassA` gets introduced in the current namespace (depending upon where the class definition exists). The name points to this new `type` object.

Note that in the above, "executing a class definition" is not the same thing as executing any of the functions defined in the scope of that class.
When we say that a "class definition is being executed", it just means that the interpreter is trying to understand what the class is all about (its members, attributes, etc). While this is happening, none of the functions of the class will themselves be executed - not even `__init__()`

### Demonstration:

(to demonstrate when exactly the class object gets created, and what happens as a consequence)

**module_a.py:**

```
print ("Global print() from mod_a")

class ClassA:
    print ("Class-level print from ClassA")
    
    def __init__(self):
        print ("Inside ClassA.__init__()")
```

**module_b.py:**

```
my_globals = globals()
print (f"Before import, len(my_globals) is: {len(my_globals)}")
if "ClassA" not in my_globals:
    print ("Before import, ClassA doesn't exist in globals of mod_b")
else:
    print (type(ClassA))

from mod_a import *

my_globals = globals()
```

print (f"After import, len(my_globals) is: {len(my_globals)}")    if "ClassA" not in my_globals:
print ("After import, ClassA doesn't exist in globals")
else:
print ("After import, name 'ClassA' exists")
print (f"type(ClassA) is: {type(ClassA)}")

```
ClassB = ClassA  # The name ClassB is now an alias for the same type object
                 # that the name ClassA points to
ClassB()
```

**Output (upon executing `mod_b.py`):**

```
Before import, len(my_globals) is: 5
Before import, ClassA doesn't exist in globals of mod_b  <-- print() in mod_b before import
Global print() from mod_a                                <-- print() in mod_a during import
Class-level print from ClassA                            <-- print() in mod_a during import
After import, len(my_globals) is: 6
After import, name 'ClassA' exists                       <-- print() in mod_b after import
type(ClassA) is: <class 'type'>                          <-- print() in mod_b after import
Inside ClassA.__init__()                                 <-- print() triggered by ClassB(), from __init__() of ClassA
```

### Notes on the above output:

From the above output, we can see that:

1. The name `ClassA` doesn't exist in the `global` namespace of `mod_b` until the statement `from mod_a import *` is executed in `mod_b`.
2. After execution of the `import` statement, the name `ClassA` exists in the `global` namespace of `mod_b`, and points to an object of type `type`.
3. After the assignment statement `ClassB = ClassA`, the names `ClassA` and `ClassB` both refer to the same object.
4. From hereon, there is nothing "special" or "original" about the name `ClassA` -- we could use the name `ClassB` to do the instantiation, instead of using the name `ClassA`.
5. By doing a `del ClassA`, we could even make the name `ClassA` undefined in the `global` namespace of `mod_b`, and continue to use the alias name `ClassB` (But I have not included this last bit in the above demonstration)

### Documentary reference:

Some relevant extracts from [The Python Execution Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#index-0):

1. A Python program is constructed from code blocks. A block is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a **class definition**.
2. Names refer to objects. Names are introduced by name binding operations.
3. The following constructs bind names: formal parameters to functions, import statements, **class and function definitions** (these bind the class or function name in the defining block)
4. If a name is bound at the module level, it is a global variable.